# Updating column with Replace

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mariadb-10.4

Using MySQL (MariaDB 10.4.12)

I am trying to update a column using the replace function.  I need to replace an ip address with a URL.  The value in the column is very long.

I am using:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET myColumn = REPLACE(myColumn, '192.168.9.1', 'www.mydomain.com/content')
WHERE ID = 1234;
```

When I run this, the value it updates to is very wrong.

However, if I remove the"/content" from the replace function, it updates correctly.

The data type of the column is longtext:

```
# Field, Type, Null, Key, Default, Extra
'myColumn', 'longtext', 'NO', '', NULL, ''
```

The value in this column is metadata, that is a very long string of characters/code.  In the middle is my url that I need to update.

Example: `a:4:{s:5:"child";a:1:{s:0:"";a:1:{s:3:"rss";a:1:{i:0;a:6:{s:4:"data";s:3:"` and on and on and on.

Additionally, if I just select with the REPLACE() function, it returns the correct value.

Is there an issue with having a forward-slash ("/") in the replace function or update statement?

Thanks
-M

Comment: What is the data type of myColumn? You can type `show columns from mytable` to show all the columns and their datatypes like this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-columns.html. Edit your question and ad the output.

Comment: you must show soemdata of your column

Comment: The column datatype in question is longtext.  The values are metadata.  Like... "a:4:{s:5:"child";a:1:{s:0:"";a:1:{s:3:"rss";a:1:{i:0;a:6:{s:4:"data";s:3:"" that goes on for a long time.

Comment: Hmm, I cannot replicate that. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=3cbc74804fafd8c99e8cd26dd19fd7b4 example that is a created based on your example. I am able to update fine on mariadb-10.4. Are you getting very wrong answer or very long answer?

Comment: @zedfoxus - Please ask for `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; it provides more than `DESCRIBE` or `SHOW COLUMNS`.

Comment: @user8723089 - There is nothing special about _forward_ slash in that context.